# 07 Kia Rio drivers side headlight only works on high beam

Tags: troubleshooting, headlight, bulbs

I have tested both bulbs on passenger side and high and low work great for both bulbs. High beam works on both sides, no low beam on drivers side. Is there any kind of separate fuse for either side of the vehicle?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance and Repair!

Answer (score 0):

No fuses are usually one for high one for low beam. You should take a look at your bulb easiest test you can do is swap the bulbs of passenger and driver side. If the passenger bulb (working one) doesn't light up on your left side, try moving cables a bit to make sure you don't have loose connection. After swapping the bulbs if there still isn't working driver low beam you will have to diagnose it further.